# Is the prayer for a spouse instantly accepted?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, dua, husband-wife

I heard that when parents pray for their children Allah accepts it instantly. Does Husband-wife's prayer does the same thing?

Comment: None can pray (Salat the worship) for any other person. But we may perform supplication (du'a which in the Arabic language could also be referred to as salat, but which isn't a worship which is a due on any mukallaf) for anybody else.

Comment: Oh thanks.... I didn’t know this fact......  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard what you heard, instead there be hadith:

[Sources](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D9%88%D9%8E%D8%AF%D9%8E%D8%B9%D9%92%D9%88%D9%8E%D8%A9%D9%8F%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%92%D9%88%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%90%D8%AF%D9%90):

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Three supplications are answered
>   without doubt. The supplication of the oppressed, the supplication of
>   the traveller, and the supplication of the parent for his son."

Hadith does not say husband-wife.

Comment: Which one should i believe?read the 1st comment....i am confused

Comment: Comment does not say anything different. Prayer can mean salah (worship) or du'a (supplication, asking Allah to do something). Salah is only for Allah, Du'a is for any purpose.